# Validate startDate endDate in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, primeng

I am trying to implement an Angular 6 form with startDate and endDate
using PrimeNg Calendar (DatePicker), both dates of type Date.

How can I validate that startDate <= endDate and endDate >= startDate.
It is a cross validation.
One would think Angular might have some tool for it.
I have seen some generic Angular examples when 1 of those validations
is done, so far haven't seen both.
Maybe using Pipe?   Or any PrimeNg specific tools?

Please advise.

TIA,
Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function updateValueAndValidity, with this you can validate the control at any time, in this case when the startDate value is modified or vice versa.

Validation functions must be previously added to each formControl.

Validate startDate on endDate changed.

```
this.formGroup.get('endDate').valueChanges.subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    this.formGroup.get('startDate').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom validator.

**custom-validator.ts**

```
export function DateLessThanOrEqualsValidator(dateCompareControlName: string) {

    let thisDateControl: AbstractControl;
    let otherDateControl: AbstractControl;

    return function DateLessThanOrEqualsValidate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        if (!control.parent) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!thisDateControl) {
            thisDateControl = control;
            otherDateControl = control.parent.get(dateCompareControlName) as AbstractControl;
            if (!otherDateControl) {
                throw new Error('dateLessThanOrEqualsValidator(): other control is not found in parent group');
            }
            otherDateControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
                thisDateControl.updateValueAndValidity();
            });
        }
        if (!otherDateControl || !otherDateControl.value) {
            return null;
        }
        const date1 = thisDateControl.value;
        const date2 = otherDateControl.value;
        if (date1 !== null && date2 !== null && date1 > date2) {
            return {
                'date_less_than_or_equal': true
            };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

And use it:

```
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'startDate': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, DateLessThanOrEqualsValidator('endDate')]), // must be same "endDate"
      'endDate': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    });
```

Each time `startDate > endDate`, `myForm` will be **invalid**

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-b6pfku)

Comment: Note:  both startDate<=endDate and endDate>=startDate validators should work on the same form.

Comment: Maybe I can use Calendar functionality to make it work, set that in a startDate in HTML:     [maxDate]="myForm.get('endDate').value" or something like that?
And conversely for endDate:  [minDate]="myForm.get('startDate').value" , will that work?

Comment: startDate <= endDate validation is enough, of course endDate >= startDate. Try here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-b6pfku

Comment: I tried. So if I set say startDate 08/07/2020 and then endDate 08/01/2020, it shows startDate as invalid, which is wrong, it should show endDate. Agree?